# Suppress Active X Warning "An Active X control on this page" in IE 11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex, hta

I have an Oracle forms application that has be run in IE, currently we're on 11.

It calls an outside web app through a URL, that needs to run in Chrome.

Because launching a URL in IE will result in the page opening in IE, I am using the following code to force it to go to Chrome:

```
var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
ws.Exec('"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe"' +
            ' -url ' + url);
```

It works, but everytime it opens the Chrome window, it first throws a pop up message that says "An Active X control on this page might be unsafe" that you need to click "Yes" on before it will launch. I want to get rid of that message.

I have tried using the mark of the web testing with google:

```
<!-- saved from url=(0022)http://www.google.com/ -->
```

It did not work.

I tried changing the page the code snippet is in to an .hta file, which got rid of the message but replaced it with a new pop up saying "What would you like to do with this file".

I tried adding the following registry values:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0]
"1201"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0] "1201="dword:00000000"
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0] "1201"=dword:00000000
[HKEY_USERS\S-1-5-18\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\0] "1201="dword:00000000"
```

I have "Allow active content to run in files on My Computer" checked off in the IE settings.

Nothing will get rid of that stupid message.

Any ideas please?

Comment: Not sure this is the way to approach the problem. If the Web app needs to run in Chrome, use browser detection to identify what browser they are using and block them from using IE. You could also recommend what browser they should be using.

Comment: The page that needs to be run in Chrome, is being launched from a page that needs to be run in IE. These are the circumstances I'm stuck with unfortunately

Comment: HTA won't show that warning message, you're running the app in IE. If you can't make it run as HTA, then you've to downgrade the security options heavily to hide the pop-up. Open Internet options and Security tab. If you're running the app in a local network (file://), click Intranet Zone (Internet Zone otherwise), then click Edit button (beside the Defaults button), a list of options will open. Find ActiveX Components section, and allow execution of all ActiveX items in the list. Notice that you should __use IE browser with your own app only__, if you're allowing ActiveX on Internet Zone.

Comment: I can get it to work using an .hta, the problem is that it still has a pop up saying "what would you like to do with this file?" when the .hta is launched. My goal is to get rid of all pop ups. I'll check with the security group about what can be done with IE security settings

Comment: If a HTA shows these pop-ups, then downgrade the Intranet Zone security only in the Internet Options of IE.

Comment: Try to change two settings in the Internet Options dialog box of Internet Explorer: check the “Allow active content to run in files on My Computer” option in the Advanced page of the Internet Options. check the “Initialize and script ActiveX controls not marked as safe” option in the Security page of the Internet Options (Internet Zone). More detail information, please check [this link](https://medium.com/@bkey76/safely-disable-the-windows-security-warning-dialog-for-an-activex-control-1d47c43cc5d5).

Answer (score 0):

Add this towards the beginning of your script

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
Set objEnv = objShell.Environment("PROCESS")
objEnv("SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS") = 1
```

and remove it at the end

```
objEnv.Remove("SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS")
```

Comment: I still get a message when I out those lines in my script